# Does a plug-in selector bivariate kernel density estimator with weights exist for python?

Tags: python, r, statistics, kernel-density

I am trying to calculate the kernel density estimate for a set of weighted bivariate data points. I am currently using [KDEpy.FFTKDE](https://kdepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API.html#KDEpy.FFTKDE.FFTKDE). However, this does not provide a method for automatically calculating the bandwidth. Do you know if there exists a multivariate KDE estimator which allows the data to be weighted and uses a plug-in method to calculate the bandwidth for python?

I typically have about 10^6 data points so I believe cross-validation will be too computationally slow.

[fastkde](https://pypi.org/project/fastkde/) nearly provides what I want but doesn't allow the data to be weighted.

I believe the kde function inside of the sm package in R provides what I want (see page 33 of [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ks/ks.pdf)). However, I've never programmed in R.

Answer (score 0):

You may try scipy.stats.gaussian_kde but the speed of computing will be slower compare to KDEpy.FFTKDE.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).